# How do I register a request with a generic type in MediatR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, mediatr

I have the following class

```
SearchQuery<TEntity>
```

And it's used with MediatR like this on a controller:

```
await Mediator.Send(
    new SearchQuery<TEntity>(
        new PageInformation(pageNumber, pageSize), Request.Query));
```

And I've registered MediatR with the service collection in my app as follows:

```
services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

The `SearchQuery` class is in the correct namespace, it's in the same place as every other one which has been created, but when I run the application, I receive the following error.

> MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[AssetManagement.Core.Application.Search.Queries.SearchQuery`1[AssetManagement.Core.Domain.Entities.TEntity],AssetManagement.Core.Application.Models.PaginatedList`1[AssetManagement.Core.Domain.Entities.TEntity]]. Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub for examples

The `SearchQuery<T>` class in detail:

```
public class SearchQuery<T> : IRequest<PaginatedList<T>>
{
    public SearchQuery(
        PageInformation pageInformation,
        IQueryCollection searchQueryCollection)
    {
        QueryCollection = searchQueryCollection;
        PageInformation = pageInformation;
    }
    public IQueryCollection QueryCollection { get; }
    public PageInformation PageInformation { get; }
}

public class SearchQueryHandler<T>
    : IRequestHandler<SearchQuery<T>, PaginatedList<T>>
{
    private readonly IFormsDbContext _formsContext;

    public SearchQueryHandler(IFormsDbContext formsContext)
    {
        _formsContext = formsContext;
    }

    public Task<PaginatedList<T>> Handle(
        SearchQuery<T> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //return PaginatedList<Entity> here?
        ...
    }
}
```

I've tried to register the type with the service collection as below

```
services.AddTransient(
    typeof(IRequestHandler<,>),
    typeof(SearchQueryHandler<TEntity>));
```

But then receive the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Open generic service type 'MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[TRequest,TResponse]' requires registering an open generic implementation type

I have tried various other ways of resolving this, but I feel I'm going around in circles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible with MS.DI. You are trying to map the open-generic interface `IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>` to an open-generic implementation `SearchQueryHandler<T>`. But with your desired mapping, the generic type arguments of `IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>`, namely `TRequest` and `TResponse`, do not exactly map to that of `SearchQueryHandler<T>`.

When it comes to generics, MS.DI is very simplistic. To be able to make a mapping, MS.DI must be able to fill in the generic type arguments of the abstraction directly into the created implementation. To make it less abstract, MS.DI simply calls `.MakeGenericType()` similar to the following code:

```cs
Type registeredOpenImplementation = typeof(SearchQueryHandler<>);

Type requestedAbstraction =
    typeof(IRequestHandler<SearchQuery<Customer>, PaginatedList<Customer>>);

Type closedImplementationToResolve =
    registeredOpenImplementation
        .MakeGenericType(requestedAbstraction.GetGenericTypeArguments());
```

The call to `MakeGenericType`, however, would completely fail, because:

1. The incorrect number of types is supplied. `requestedAbstraction.GetGenericTypeArguments()` returns two types, while `registeredOpenImplementation` has one.
2. The types do not match, because of the type constraints on `SearchQueryHandler<T>`. Where `SearchQuery<Customer>` is extracted from the abstraction, `SearchQueryHandler<T>` expects `Customer`.

Long story short, MS.DI is not built for your use case. You have two options:

1. Switch to a different DI Container. There are mature DI Containers that support these kinds of registrations. I can't provide you with a full list of all DI Containers that support your requirements, but I know for sure that Autofac and Simple Injector have decent support for generics.
2. Step away from this kind of Batch-Registration and register all closed-generic types manually. For instance:

   ```
   services.AddTransient<
      IRequestHandler<SearchQuery<Customer>, PaginatedList<Customer>>,
      SearchQueryHandler<Customer>>();
   services.AddTransient<
      IRequestHandler<SearchQuery<Order>, PaginatedList<Order>>,
      SearchQueryHandler<Order>>();
   services.AddTransient<
      IRequestHandler<SearchQuery<Product>, PaginatedList<Product>>,
      SearchQueryHandler<Product>>();
   services.AddTransient<
      IRequestHandler<SearchQuery<Employee>, PaginatedList<Employee>>,
      SearchQueryHandler<Employee>>();
   // etc
   ```

Comment: _"What you are trying to achieve (map the open-generic interface IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> to an open-generic implementation SearchQueryHandler<T>) is not possible with MS.DI out of the box."_, this has changed with .NET 5: https://jimmybogard.com/constrained-open-generics-support-merged-in-net-core-di-container/

Comment: If you read the supplied article closely, you'll notice that Jimmy's pull request is solely about support for variance, not for the type of complex mappings of type constraints that OP is trying to achieve. You can try it out yourself. MS.DI will throw an exception similar to the following: "The number of generic arguments provided doesn't equal the arity of the generic type definition."

Comment: Huh. I read the article at the time and left thinking "oh I wont have to use autofac for this anymore" and didn't really question it/tried it. You're right, I stand corrected.